# Selenium - sendKeys() function is not working for file upload

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am using eclipse Helios Version: Helios Service Release 1,Build id: 20100917-0705 with selenium 3.141.59 but when I am trying to use this `sendKeys()` function then it is showing error message:

```java
The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

The Source code is:

```java
package AutomationFramework;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
//import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
//import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
//import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;


public class HandleFileupload {

    public static WebDriver driver = null;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    
        System.getProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","G:\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://html.com/input-type-file/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS );
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='fileupload']")).sendKeys("filupload");
                
    }

}
```

Comment: Show the code please

Comment: It seems like the issue usually occurs when you have different jdk and jre version . Endure that both jdk and jre are of same java version

Comment: Please send me step by step installation of selenium web driver with proper versions. i think there is some problem in my software or jar files. i don't know how would i check whether my java environment is set up correctly or my class & file name is same or not

Comment: run java --version and javac --version in cmd

Comment: https://www.dummies.com/programming/java/how-to-configure-java-in-eclipse/

Comment: I have installed eclipse photon version and selenium standalone server and now everything is working fine. Thanks for your support

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/epp/2020-03/R/eclipse-inst-win64.exe install the latest version to avoid letter incompatibility issues

Comment: Can i know about this element? //*[@id='fileupload']

Comment: Please share your HTML to understand what element you are trying to play with.

Answer (score 1):

From the sample code it can be seen that you are trying to pass file name for a file upload (`<input type="file">`) element.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='fileupload']")).sendKeys("filupload");
```

You need pass the full path of the file that you want to upload in the above line.

So the change in your code would look something like this,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='fileupload']")).sendKeys("C:\\\\Users\\Achint\\Desktop\\Files\\Filename.txt");
```

This should work out for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you use sendkeys command for File upload button

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='fileupload']")).sendKeys("filupload");
```

pass file path to sendkeys parameter and try

Answer (score 0):

In software testing companies different types of testing services are provided by qa engineers like security testing services etc.

In the above scenario, when we are uploading any file using Selenium whose fileupload button id = 'fileupload', Then we have to pass file path to the 'SendKeys' function.

Answer (score 0):

In Software qa services we can do by multiple ways.
By selenium in above code we need to update the line to :
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='fileupload']")).sendKeys("locationofTheFilePlaced");
in locationofTheFilePlaced please add the location of the file present in the framework.
Moreover we can achieve this using the AutoIT. Please refer below link for the details upload of file using AutoIT.
https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/file-upload-in-selenium/